# loading data into hdfs in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a Hadoop cluster consisting of 3 Nodes.  I want to load a 180 GB file into HDFS as fast as possible. I know neither -put nor -copyFromLocal are going to help me in this as they are single threaded.

I'm thinking in terms of Map/Reduce. Is there a way to distribute the loading process to the nodes themselves. So each node will load a part of the file say 60 GB each. I don't want to do this manually from each node (that defeats the purpose). If there is way to do this using Java and Map/Reduce I would love to read about it. I know Hadoop can process wildcard input files. Say each 60GB chunk is named like this: file_1, file_2, file_3..I can then use file_* for my next MR jobs. The trouble I'm having is understanding how to efficiently load the file first into hadoop in a fast / multi-threaded way.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

distcp - seems to be doing parallel copying into HDFS but only between clusters, and not within a cluster. I wonder why they didn't think of that, and if they did, what are the limitations or bottlenecks around this. 
Also http://blog.syncsort.com/2012/06/moving-data-into-hadoop-faster/ seems to document benchmarks around this topic but they're using DMExpress (commercial tool) to do the loading. It would be great to have an Open Source alternative.

Comment: Given that you read that 180gb file from a single harddisk, I doubt that you can get much faster than doing it sequentially, because the HDD is the bottleneck. How would a MapReduce Mapper access stuff on a local disk of a single server? I hope you see why they don't added this to distcp, because it makes no sense (No speedup, disk and network is limiting- that just doesn't scale).

Answer (score 0):

With your configuration, I don't know if parallelization of writes improve your performances because you want to write one file.

Suppose we have default configuration. Default replication factor is 3, so your file is considered as written when each blocks of your file is written on 3 machines of your cluster (in your case, in all machines of your cluster).

If you have more than one disk per machine, dividing your file on smallest part (as part as disk used by HDFS on one machine) can help to improve writing performance only if your application is the only one to use the cluster and you are not limited by your network. In this case your bottleneck is your disks.

If you can manage divided file on your clients a simple way to be sure all parts of your file is copied on HDFS is to create a directory which is the name of your file concatenated with a suffix which showing that the file is on copy. This directory contains all parts of your file. When all copying threads are finished you can rename the directory without suffix. Your clients can access to all parts of file only when suffix is removed. Rename consists on an operation in metadata on Namenode it is a fastest operation as compared as file copy.

Others solutions :

- Usage of a marker file is not the best option because you lose an HDFS block (by default block size if 128 MB).
- Recreating the file from its parts is similar to a rewriting of data so it is inefficient.